# Add a mouse event into the textfield create by array in java

Tags: java, swing

This is the code of a button action listener, after I press this button , will set the GridLayout size, and add the textfield inside, but when I try to add mouse event into the text will got problem(the function I want is when I press the proID[0],then the proName[0] will settext to "0" and proID[1],then the proName[1] will settext to "1" and next all )

```
static int k = 1;
static int i = 1;
static int countttt = 0;
private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JTextField proID[] = new JTextField[i];
    JTextField proName[] = new JTextField[i];
    JTextField pUnitPrice[] = new JTextField[i];
    JTextField Qty[] = new JTextField[i];
    JTextField Linetotal[] = new JTextField[i];


    GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(k, 5, 1, 1);
    jPanel6.setLayout(experimentLayout);
    proID[countttt] = new JTextField("a" + countttt);
    proName[countttt] = new JTextField();
    pUnitPrice[countttt] = new JTextField();
    Qty[countttt] = new JTextField();
    Linetotal[countttt] = new JTextField();


    proID[countttt].addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(countttt);
            proName[countttt].setText(countttt);
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });

    jPanel6.add(proID[countttt]);
    jPanel6.add(proName[countttt]);
    jPanel6.add(pUnitPrice[countttt]);
    jPanel6.add(Qty[countttt]);
    jPanel6.add(Linetotal[countttt]);
    i++;
    countttt++;
    k++;
    jPanel6.repaint();
    jPanel6.revalidate();


}
```

Comment: Don't you need a for loop of some kind in there??

Comment: at which part? before addMouseListener?

Comment: Felix, you have an array of components, right? Your code above only creates one JTextField in the array, the one at position 0, correct? Well, can't you see that you'd need a for loop to create and set up your 6 fields? The loop would start at the `proID[countttt] = new JTextField("a" + countttt);` line, the line where you try to initialize the components of your array (but only initialize one).

Comment: for(int q=0;q<=countttt;q++){

proID[q] = new JTextField("a" + countttt);

}
add this ?

Comment: You'll want to not post code in comments as it is very difficult to read. You'll want your for loop to be a lot bigger to have many lines so as to fully set up each JTextArea. Play with this -- you'll figure it out.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).